# Aligning a table with title in a GridSpec

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-gridspec

I have the following page layout with two charts up top, a map, and a table.

As you can see in the result, the table title is not aligned with the Map title, and there is way too much space between bottom of Fig 1 and top of Map 1. Ideally I want the map and the table to be aligned (vertically) and with the Map and Table titles also aligned.

How would I make that happen?

[image: Result]

```
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
from blume.table import table

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(11, 8.5))
fig.suptitle(f"Water intensity of {ti}")
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(2, 2, height_ratios=[1, 2])
ax = fig.add_subplot(gs[0, 0])
ax.set_title("Fig 1")
ax = fig.add_subplot(gs[0, 1])
ax.set_title("Fig 2")
ax = fig.add_subplot(gs[1, 0])
ax.set_title("Map 1")
world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))

world.plot(ax=ax)
ax = fig.add_subplot(gs[1, 1])
ax.set_axis_off()
tab = table(ax,
    cellText=["10","20"],
    colLabels=[1,2],
    rowLabels=['a','b'],
    loc='center'
).scale(1,1.5)
ax.set_title("Table 1")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table position could be adjusted upwards by using
`loc='upper center'` instead of `loc='center'`.

To fix the map position within its subplot, add `ax.set_aspect('equal', anchor='N')` after `ax.set_title("Map 1")`.

The resulting page layout:
[image]